# Cron logging in /var/log/syslog

Tags: cron, syslog

I Have a rake task which executes successfully . But the cron logs it in the /var/log/syslog. Is it a genuine problem. I'm observing this issue for more than a month now, but the cron always logs it as an error in the /var/log/syslog. Is there any reason behind this.

Comment: please look at http://troy.jdmz.net/cron/

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value of the executed command and the output it prints to STDOUT and STDERR. This is the reason why cron logs it.